# How to allow an unprivileged deployer user to run a certain command with sudo in a specific path?

Tags: permissions, sudo, chmod

I created a "deployer" user

```
# Create user deployer
sudo adduser deployer
# Give the read-write-execute permissions to deployer user for directory /var/www
sudo setfacl -R -m u:deployer:rwx /var/www
```

but restricted the user only for `/var/www`

Now I'm looking for a way to allow this `deployer` user to alter the rights for specific folders in a task

Task example:

```
sudo chown -R deployer:www-data /var/www/app/storage
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx /var/www/app/storage
```

However, I get the error:

> deployer is not in the sudoers file.

Is there a way how I can give the deployer only the rights to sudo commands like these: `chown|chmod|supervisorctl|systemctl` only in the path of `/var/www/`?

My current requirements for tasks for the deployer:

```
sudo chown -R deployer:www-data /var/www/app/storage
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx /var/www/app/storage
sudo supervisorctl restart all
sudo systemctl reload php7.3-fpm
```

Comment: `systemctl` (for example) doesn't take a a path as a (mandatory) argument, so I'm not sure what you mean by allowing `systemctl` "only in the path of `/var/www`"... could you explain?

Comment: @derobert For example to do this: `sudo systemctl reload php7.3-fpm`